# Is ACE/Jet's IN operator or CHECK constraint 'broken'?

Tags: ms-access, jet

Consider the following table with a constraint that's a bit daft but simple enough to demonstrate my point. Note that, to keep things very simple, the constraint's criteria only involve literal values. The column `ID` only exists because a table must have at least one column (!!) but that column is not involved in the constraint. While a little daft (hence the name) this is perfectly legal syntax and similar to adding `WHERE 0 = 1` to a `SELECT` query to ensure it returns zero rows.

(Standard SQL DDL code, will execute in ACE/Jet's ANSI-92 Query Mode)

```
CREATE TABLE Test1 
(
   ID INTEGER NOT NULL, 
   CONSTRAINT daft_1 CHECK (5 = NULL)
);
```

The following `INSERT` succeeds:

```
INSERT INTO Test1 (ID) VALUES (1);
```

This is expected behaviour. The predicate `5 = NULL` should evaluate to `UNKNOWN`. The `INSERT` is 'given the benefit of the doubt' and succeeds. No problem there.

Consider this similar example using the `IN` operator:

```
CREATE TABLE Test2 
(
   ID INTEGER NOT NULL, 
   CONSTRAINT daft_2 CHECK (5 IN (0, 1, NULL))
);
```

The following `INSERT` fails because the constraint bites:

```
INSERT INTO Test2 (ID) VALUES (1);
```

This is unexpected behviour, by me at least. I would expect the `5 IN (0, 1, NULL)` to again be evaluated as `UNKNOWN` and the `INSERT` to succeed for the same reasons as the first example.

I would expect the logic in the second example to be the same as the following third example:

```
CREATE TABLE Test3
(
   ID INTEGER NOT NULL, 
   CONSTRAINT daft_3 CHECK((5 = 0) OR (5 = 1) OR (5 = NULL))
);
```

The following `INSERT` succeeds:

```
INSERT INTO Test3 (ID) VALUES (1);
```

This is expected behaviour.

I've tested all three examples on SQL Server and the all work as I expect i.e. all three `INSERT` statements succeed. In fact, examining the INFORMATION SCHEMA reveals that for the second example SQL Server as 'helpfully' (grrr) rewritten the constraint's clause to replace the `IN` operator with

```
((5)=NULL OR (5)=(1) OR (5)=(0))
```

So, for ACE/Jet, what is 'broken' here: the `IN` operator or the `CHECK` constraint?

Here's some VBA code to reproduce the problem using a NULLable column; also demonstrates that dropping the constraint allows the `INSERT` to succeed:

```
Sub TestJetInCheck()

  On Error Resume Next
  Kill Environ$("temp") & "\DropMe.mdb"
  On Error GoTo 0

  Dim cat
  Set cat = CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog")

  With cat
    .Create _
        "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & _
        Environ$("temp") & "\DropMe.mdb"

    With .ActiveConnection

      Dim Sql As String
      Sql = _
          "CREATE TABLE Test" & vbCr & _
          "(" & vbCr & _
          "   ID INTEGER, " & vbCr & _
          "   CONSTRAINT daft_constraint " & vbCr & _
          "      CHECK (5 IN (0, 1, NULL))" & vbCr & _
          ");"
      .Execute Sql

      Sql = "INSERT INTO Test (ID) VALUES (1);"

      On Error Resume Next
      .Execute Sql
      If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox Err.Description
      Else
        MsgBox "{{no error}}"
      End If
      On Error GoTo 0

      .Execute "ALTER TABLE Test DROP CONSTRAINT daft_constraint;"

      On Error Resume Next
      .Execute Sql
      If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox Err.Description
      Else
        MsgBox "{{no error}}"
      End If
      On Error GoTo 0

    End With

    Set .ActiveConnection = Nothing
  End With
End Sub
```

EDIT: I just thought to try this:

SELECT NULL IN (1);
-- returns NULL

SELECT 1 IN (NULL)
-- returns zero i.e. FALSE

Comment: Why don't you try doing it with DAO instead of DDL?

Comment: Two reasons: 1) I don't believe the method of the CHECK constraint's creation would affect its functioning; 2) you can't create a CHECK constraint using DAO.

Comment: ...but you have given me an idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can eliminate the `CHECK` constraint specifically by creating a Validation Rule (@David W. Fenton: sorry, I find SQL DDL and ADO and easier to write than DAO but thanks for the inspiration):

```
Sub TestJetInValidationRule()

  On Error Resume Next
  Kill Environ$("temp") & "\DropMe.mdb"
  On Error GoTo 0

  Dim cat
  Set cat = CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog")

  With cat
    .Create _
        "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & _
        Environ$("temp") & "\DropMe.mdb"

    With .ActiveConnection

      Dim Sql As String
      Sql = _
          "CREATE TABLE Test" & vbCr & _
          "(" & vbCr & _
          "   ID INTEGER" & vbCr & _
          ");"
      .Execute Sql
    End With

    ' Create Validation Rules
    Dim jeng
    Set jeng = CreateObject("JRO.JetEngine")
    jeng.RefreshCache .ActiveConnection

    .Tables("Test").Columns("ID") _
    .Properties("Jet OLEDB:Column Validation Rule").value = _
    "5 IN (0, 1, NULL)"

    jeng.RefreshCache .ActiveConnection

    With .ActiveConnection

      Sql = "INSERT INTO Test (ID) VALUES (1);"

      On Error Resume Next
      .Execute Sql
      If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox Err.Description
      Else
        MsgBox "{{no error}}"
      End If
      On Error GoTo 0

    End With

    Set .ActiveConnection = Nothing
  End With
End Sub
```

The Validation Rule bites and INSERT fails. Therefore, I suspect the IN clause is behaving unexpectedly. I shall be using nested OR clauses in future!